# Transform contour line as straight line

Tags: python, opencv, math

I have this image:
[image: Lines]
I extracted lines using

```
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

I have 4 contours then. My goal is to convert this lines as infinite straight lines (so I can detect overlap points of those lines then. Is this somehow possible? I tried hough lines, but it gives unpredictable solutions, in some cases lines doesnt have enough length, or there is much more lines than just one.

Comment: Use cv2.HoughLines() in place of contours. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a

Comment: I mentoined that in question, that I tried hough lines, but they are not enough, they dont give me proper result, right side is mostly not covered, and if it is, then top/bottom has a really lot of candidates then

Comment: Can you share the data for `contours` please?

Comment: Implement a simple RANSAC line fitting.

Comment: @Corralien I dont want to push there long array, you can extract contours from that image with findContours as I mentoined in question...

maybe what I realize, result of findContours is not a line, it is shape around line, so that can be problem probably for houghTransform also then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fitLine](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf849da1fdafa67ee84b1e9a23b93f91f) to fit a straight line to a contour.

```
void cv::fitLine (
        InputArray      points,
        OutputArray     line,
        int     distType,
        double      param,
        double      reps,
        double      aeps 
    )
```

For 2D lines, it'll output the line as (vx, vy, x0, y0):

> where (vx, vy) is a normalized vector collinear to the line and (x0,
> y0) is a point on the line

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late but you can use:

0. Prepare data from **your image** (not `contours`):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('test2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 100)
```

1. A clustering method to group your `contours` like `KMeans`:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Get the list of points
points = np.argwhere(edged)

# Create 4 clusters of points
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4).fit(points)
```

2. Now, find the slope `m` and the intercept `b` coefficients from `y = mx + b` with `LinearRegression` (or `np.polyfit`):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Find coefficients
coeffs = []
for i in range(4):
    idx = np.where(i == kmeans.labels_)[0]
    x = points[idx, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
    y = points[idx, 1]

    reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
    m, b = reg.coef_[0], reg.intercept_  
    coeffs.append((m, b))

    plt.scatter(x, y, s=0.1)
    plt.axline(xy1=(0, b), slope=m, color='k', zorder=-1, lw=0.5)

plt.xlim(0, image.shape[0])
plt.ylim(0, image.shape[1])
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
>>> coeffs
[(101.53675590518964, -6345.8426544453905),
 (-68.00736350967681, 62626.8080715293),
 (-0.00030668339485539364, 318.2125762056594),
 (0.001297826071265324, 1622.8759316729752)]
```

[image]

Now you can find the intersection between equations.